# Algorithm : Median of two sorted array of different sizes

Tags: arrays, algorithm, median

Here is a code pasted from [here](http://leetcode.com/2011/03/median-of-two-sorted-arrays.html#comment-1053)

I'm unable to understand what it is doing. I could think of a simple algorithm to find median of two sorted arrays when merged. The idea is to compare the medians (m1, m2) of both the arrays and if `m1 < m2` find median of right first subarray from m1 and left second subarray upto m2. The following code is doing it in the same lines but I'm unable to understand it completely.

```
double findMedian(int A[], int B[], int l, int r, int nA, int nB) {
    if (l>r)
        return findMedian(B, A, max(0, (nA+nB)/2-nA), min(nB, (nA+nB)/2), nB, nA); //What does the min/max do here
    int i = (l+r)/2;
    int j = (nA+nB)/2 – i – 1;
    if (j>=0 && A[i] < B[j])
        return findMedian(A, B, i+1, r, nA, nB);
    else if (j<nB-1 && A[i] > B[j+1])
        return findMedian(A, B, l, i-1, nA, nB);
    else {
        if ( (nA+nB)%2 == 1 ) return A[i];
        else if (i>0) return (A[i]+max(B[j], A[i-1]))/2.0; //I couldn't understand this
        else return (A[i]+B[j])/2.0;
    }
}

double findMedianSortedArrays(int A[], int n, int B[], int m) {
    if (n<m)
        return findMedian(A, B, 0, n-1, n, m);
    else
        return findMedian(B, A, 0, m-1, m, n);
}
```

What does the second line of the code do? Apart from that I couldn't comprehend how the last `else` block will return a median. will `i` index contain the median when `n + m` is odd?

Any help, links or pointers are appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should ask the one who wrote this part of code ?

Comment: If A={1;1} B={0;0;6;6} the algorithm return 3.5 but the correct answer is 1. If A={1;1} B={0;6}  there is buffer overflow.

Comment: This is a question from leetcode (here is the [link](http://oj.leetcode.com/problems/median-of-two-sorted-arrays/)). As mentioned by @Mr K, the algorithm that you provide won't give correct result. Why bother to understand it at all?

Answer (score -2):

This is the pseudocode for what you want to do .
I assume `ar1` and `ar2` be the input arrays and size of both is `n`.

Algorithm:

```
1) Calculate the medians m1 and m2 of the input arrays ar1[] 
   and ar2[] respectively.  
2) If m1 and m2 both are equal then we are done.
     return m1 (or m2)  
3) If m1 is greater than m2, then median is present in one 
   of the below two subarrays.  
    a)  From first element of ar1 to m1 (ar1[0...|_n/2_|])  
    b)  From m2 to last element of ar2  (ar2[|_n/2_|...n-1])  
4) If m2 is greater than m1, then median is present in one      
   of the below two subarrays.  
   a)  From m1 to last element of ar1  (ar1[|_n/2_|...n-1])  
   b)  From first element of ar2 to m2 (ar2[0...|_n/2_|])  
5) Repeat the above process until size of both the subarrays 
   becomes 2.  
6) If size of the two arrays is 2 then use below formula to get   
  the median.  
    Median = (max(ar1[0], ar2[0]) + min(ar1[1], ar2[1]))/2
```

Now , you can code it into any language of your choice .

Hope this helps !

Comment: How do you choose the subarrays, you will look for the median in steps 3 & 4 ? What is the computation if the size of an subarray is 1 in the step 6 ?

Comment: then median will be (ar1[0], ar2[0])/2

Comment: What if the sizes of both array are different?

Comment: @tonymiao the above solution works only for same sized arrays . For unequal sized arrays , algorithm would have to be modified because we will not be able to divide them into equal halves , so at terminating step , we can't just take assumption of only 2 elements / equal elements .